Failed to connect to FIWARE Cygnus 3.8.0
To set up MongoDB and PostgreSQL backends on FIWARE Cygnus 3.8.0, I created the following docker-compose.yml file:
services:

  orion:
    image: telefonicaiot/fiware-orion:3.12.0
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    ports:
      - 1026:1026

  mongo:
    image: mongo:4.4
    ports:
      - 27017:27017

  cygnus:
    image: telefonicaiot/fiware-cygnus:3.8.0
    depends_on:
      - mongo
      - postgres
    environment:
      - CYGNUS_API_PORT=5080
      - CYGNUS_MONGO_SERVICE_PORT=5051
      - CYGNUS_MONGO_HOSTS=mongo:27017
      - CYGNUS_POSTGRESQL_SERVICE_PORT=5055
      - CYGNUS_POSTGRESQL_HOST=postgres
      - CYGNUS_POSTGRESQL_PORT=5432
      - CYGNUS_POSTGRESQL_USER=postgres
      - CYGNUS_POSTGRESQL_PASS=postgres
      - CYGNUS_MULTIAGENT=true
      - CYGNUS_LOG_LEVEL=debug
    ports:
      - 5080:5080
      - 5051:5051
      - 5055:5055

  postgres:
    image: postgres:15
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres

Then, I run it.
docker compose up -d

I tried sanity check for cygnus. I wanted to get a version of Cygnus.
I got the following error when trying to get a version:
$ curl http://localhost:5080/v1/version
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Is there something wrong with my configuration?
The log of Cygnus was as shown:
$ docker compose logs cygnus
cygnus-1  | INFO: Using JAVA_OPTS: <-Xms2048m -Xmx4096m>
cygnus-1  | Warning: JAVA_HOME is not set!
cygnus-1  | + exec /usr/bin/java -Xms2048m -Xmx4096m -Dflume.root.logger=debug,LOGFILE -Duser.timezone=UTC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp '/opt/apache-flume/conf:/opt/apache-flume/lib/*:/opt/apache-flume/plugins.d/cygnus/lib/*:/opt/apache-flume/plugins.d/cygnus/libext/*' -Djava.library.path= com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication -f /opt/apache-flume/conf/agent_mongo.conf -n cygnus-ngsi -p 5081
cygnus-1  | Warning: JAVA_HOME is not set!
cygnus-1  | + exec /usr/bin/java -Xms2048m -Xmx4096m -Dflume.root.logger=debug,LOGFILE -Duser.timezone=UTC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp '/opt/apache-flume/conf:/opt/apache-flume/lib/*:/opt/apache-flume/plugins.d/cygnus/lib/*:/opt/apache-flume/plugins.d/cygnus/libext/*' -Djava.library.path= com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication -f /opt/apache-flume/conf/agent_postgresql.conf -n cygnus-ngsi -p 5084
cygnus-1  | SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
cygnus-1  | SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/apache-flume/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.18.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
cygnus-1  | SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/apache-flume/plugins.d/cygnus/lib/cygnus-ngsi-3.8.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
cygnus-1  | SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/apache-flume/plugins.d/cygnus/libext/cygnus-common-3.8.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
cygnus-1  | SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
cygnus-1  | SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
cygnus-1  | SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/apache-flume/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.18.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
cygnus-1  | SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/apache-flume/plugins.d/cygnus/lib/cygnus-ngsi-3.8.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
cygnus-1  | SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/apache-flume/plugins.d/cygnus/libext/cygnus-common-3.8.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
cygnus-1  | SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
cygnus-1  | SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
cygnus-1  | SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.312Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.orion-sink.orion_fiware_path =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.317Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.postgresql_username =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.317Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mysql-sink.mysql_username =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.317Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_auth_source =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.318Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.orion-sink.orion_fiware =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.318Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.sth-sink.mongo_password =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.319Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.orion-sink.orion_password =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.319Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.sth-sink.mongo_username =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.319Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.sth-sink.mongo_replica_set =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.320Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_username =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.320Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.arcgis-sink.arcgis_password =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.320Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mysql-sink.mysql_password =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.321Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.postgresql_password =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.321Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.orion-sink.orion_username =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.321Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.sth-sink.mongo_auth_source =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.322Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgis-sink.postgis_username =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.322Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.arcgis-sink.arcgis_username =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.322Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_replica_set =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.323Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs_username =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.323Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.api_key =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.323Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgis-sink.postgis_password =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.323Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_password =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.324Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.hdfs-sink.oauth2_token =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.324Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=validateConfigFilterSet | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[623] : Agent configuration for 'cygnus-ngsi' has no configfilters.
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.392Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.orion-sink.orion_fiware_path =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.397Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mysql-sink.mysql_username =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.397Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_auth_source =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.397Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.orion-sink.orion_fiware =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.398Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.sth-sink.mongo_password =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.398Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.orion-sink.orion_password =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.399Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.sth-sink.mongo_username =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.399Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.sth-sink.mongo_replica_set =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.399Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_username =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.400Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.arcgis-sink.arcgis_password =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.400Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mysql-sink.mysql_password =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.400Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.orion-sink.orion_username =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.401Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.sth-sink.mongo_auth_source =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.401Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgis-sink.postgis_username =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.402Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.arcgis-sink.arcgis_username =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.402Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_replica_set =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.402Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs_username =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.403Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.api_key =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.403Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgis-sink.postgis_password =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.403Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_password =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.404Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=<init> | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[126] : Configuration property ignored: cygnus-ngsi.sinks.hdfs-sink.oauth2_token =
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:30.404Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=N/A | op=validateConfigFilterSet | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[623] : Agent configuration for 'cygnus-ngsi' has no configfilters.
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:31.137Z | lvl=WARN | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp= | op=checkPathsWithUncoveredHttpMethods | msg=org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler[759] : ServletContext@o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@2ceea862{/,null,STARTING} has uncovered http methods for path: /*
cygnus-1  | time=2024-06-02T00:50:31.175Z | lvl=WARN | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp= | op=checkPathsWithUncoveredHttpMethods | msg=org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler[759] : ServletContext@o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4f8af238{/,null,STARTING} has uncovered http methods for path: /*
cygnus-1  |   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
cygnus-1  |                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
cygnus-1  | curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 5080 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server

But, when I set up MongoDB, MySQL and PostgreSQL backends, I was able to get the cygnus version.
services:

  orion:
    image: telefonicaiot/fiware-orion:3.12.0
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    ports:
      - 1026:1026

  mongo:
    image: mongo:4.4
    ports:
      - 27017:27017

  cygnus:
    image: telefonicaiot/fiware-cygnus:3.8.0
    depends_on:
      - mongo
      - mysql
      - postgres
    environment:
      - CYGNUS_API_PORT=5080
      - CYGNUS_MONGO_SERVICE_PORT=5051
      - CYGNUS_MONGO_HOSTS=mongo:27017
      - CYGNUS_MYSQL_SERVICE_PORT=5050
      - CYGNUS_MYSQL_HOST=mysql
      - CYGNUS_MYSQL_PORT=3306
      - CYGNUS_MYSQL_USER=root
      - CYGNUS_MYSQL_PASS=mysql
      - CYGNUS_POSTGRESQL_SERVICE_PORT=5055
      - CYGNUS_POSTGRESQL_HOST=postgres
      - CYGNUS_POSTGRESQL_PORT=5432
      - CYGNUS_POSTGRESQL_USER=postgres
      - CYGNUS_POSTGRESQL_PASS=postgres
      - CYGNUS_MULTIAGENT=true
      - CYGNUS_LOG_LEVEL=debug
    ports:
      - 5080:5080
      - 5051:5051
      - 5050:5050
      - 5055:5055

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.1
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysql

  postgres:
    image: postgres:15
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres

$ curl http://localhost:5080/v1/version
{"success":"true","version":"3.8.0.f62eff701c01df1f708e0c9484e48e7b9bd9b1ed"}

My environment is as shown:
OS: Ubuntu 2204
Arch: x86_64
Docker: Docker version 26.1.3, build b72abbb
Docker compose: Docker Compose version v2.27.0
Linux ubuntu 6.5.0-35-generic #35~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue May  7 09:00:52 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

The agent.conf file is as shown:
$ docker compose up -d
[+] Running 5/5
 ✔ Network cygnus_default       Created                                                                                                     0.0s
 ✔ Container cygnus-mongo-1     Started                                                                                                     0.6s
 ✔ Container cygnus-postgres-1  Started                                                                                                     0.6s
 ✔ Container cygnus-orion-1     Started                                                                                                     1.1s
 ✔ Container cygnus-cygnus-1    Started                                                                                                     1.2s

$ docker compose ps
NAME                IMAGE                               COMMAND                   SERVICE    CREATED         STATUS         PORTS
cygnus-cygnus-1     telefonicaiot/fiware-cygnus:3.8.0   "/cygnus-entrypoint.…"   cygnus     9 minutes ago   Up 9 minutes   0.0.0.0:5051->5051/tcp, :::5051->5051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5055->5055/tcp, :::5055->5055/tcp, 5050/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5080->5080/tcp, :::5080->5080/tcp
cygnus-mongo-1      mongo:4.4                           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   mongo      9 minutes ago   Up 9 minutes   0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp, :::27017->27017/tcp
cygnus-postgres-1   postgres:15                         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   postgres   9 minutes ago   Up 9 minutes   5432/tcp

$ curl http://localhost:5080/v1/version
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

$ docker compose exec cygnus bash

root@2357e22612da:/opt/fiware-cygnus# echo ${FLUME_HOME}/conf
/opt/apache-flume/conf

root@2357e22612da:/opt/fiware-cygnus# ls ${FLUME_HOME}/conf
agent.conf        agent_postgresql.conf  flume-conf.properties.template  flume-env.sh.template  log4j2.xml
agent_mongo.conf  cartodb_keys.conf      flume-env.ps1.template          log4j2.properties      name_mappings.conf

root@2357e22612da:/opt/fiware-cygnus# cat ${FLUME_HOME}/conf/agent.conf
#
# Copyright 2016 Telefonica Investigación y Desarrollo, S.A.U
#
# This file is part of fiware-cygnus (FI-WARE project).
#
# fiware-cygnus is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU Affero
# General Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or (at your
# option) any later version.
# fiware-cygnus is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the
# implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU Affero General Public License
# for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU Affero General Public License along with fiware-cygnus. If not, see
# http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
#
# For those usages not covered by the GNU Affero General Public License please contact with iot_support at tid dot es
#

cygnus-ngsi.sources = http-source
cygnus-ngsi.sinks =
cygnus-ngsi.channels =

cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.channels = mysql-channel mongo-channel sth-channel ckan-channel hdfs-channel cartodb-channel postgresql-channel orion-channel postgis-channel elasticsearch-channel
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.port = 5050
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.NGSIRestHandler
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.notification_target = /notify
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.default_service = default
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.default_service_path = /
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors = ts
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.ts.type = timestamp
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.nmi.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.NGSINameMappingsInterceptor$Builder
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.nmi.name_mappings_conf_file = /opt/apache-flume/conf/name_mappings.conf

cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mysql-sink.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSIMySQLSink
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mysql-sink.channel = mysql-channel
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mysql-sink.enable_encoding = false
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mysql-sink.enable_name_mappings = false
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mysql-sink.enable_lowercase = false
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mysql-sink.data_model = dm-by-entity
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mysql-sink.mysql_host = iot-mysql
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mysql-sink.mysql_port = 3306
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mysql-sink.mysql_username =
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mysql-sink.mysql_password =
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mysql-sink.attr_persistence = row
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mysql-sink.attr_native_types = false
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mysql-sink.batch_size = 1
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mysql-sink.batch_timeout = 30
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mysql-sink.batch_ttl = 10
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mysql-sink.mysql_options =

cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSIMongoSink
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.channel = mongo-channel
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.enable_encoding = false
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.enable_name_mappings = false
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.enable_lowercase = false
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.data_model = dm-by-entity
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.attr_persistence = row
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_hosts = iot-mongo:27017
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_username =
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_password =
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_auth_source =
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_replica_set =
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.db_prefix = sth_
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.collection_prefix = sth_
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.batch_size = 1
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.batch_timeout = 30
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.batch_ttl = 10
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.data_expiration = 0
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.collections_size = 0
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.max_documents = 0
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.ignore_white_spaces = true

...

# NGSIPostgreSQLSink configuration
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSIPostgreSQLSink
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.channel = postgresql-channel
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.enable_encoding = false
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.enable_name_mappings = false
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.enable_lowercase = false
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.data_model = dm-by-entity
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.postgresql_host = iot-postgresql
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.postgresql_port = 5432
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.postgresql_username =
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.postgresql_password =
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.postgresql_database = postgres
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.attr_persistence = row
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.attr_native_types = false
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.batch_size = 1
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.batch_timeout = 30
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.batch_ttl = 10
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.backend.enable_cache = false
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.postgresql-sink.postgresql_options =

...

cygnus-ngsi.channels.mysql-channel.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.channels.CygnusMemoryChannel
cygnus-ngsi.channels.mysql-channel.capacity = 100000
cygnus-ngsi.channels.mysql-channel.transactionCapacity = 10000

cygnus-ngsi.channels.postgresql-channel.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.channels.CygnusMemoryChannel
cygnus-ngsi.channels.postgresql-channel.capacity = 100000
cygnus-ngsi.channels.postgresql-channel.transactionCapacity = 10000

cygnus-ngsi.channels.postgis-channel.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.channels.CygnusMemoryChannel
cygnus-ngsi.channels.postgis-channel.capacity = 100000
cygnus-ngsi.channels.postgis-channel.transactionCapacity = 10000


cygnus-ngsi.channels.mongo-channel.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.channels.CygnusMemoryChannel
cygnus-ngsi.channels.mongo-channel.capacity = 100000
cygnus-ngsi.channels.mongo-channel.transactionCapacity = 10000

...


In order to debug this problem, could you extract the agent.conf file inside the telefonicaiot/fiware-cygnus:3.8.0 and edit your question post to include it, please?

Thank you for your reply. I added the agent.conf file that is in the running container to my post. But, the body of the text is limited to 30,000 characters, so some parts of the file have been omitted.

Could you please get into cygnus container and check the agent command which is executing?
This is an example:
$ docker exec -u 0 -ti iot-cygnus /bin/bash
root@iot-cygnus:/opt/fiware-cygnus# ps -ax
    PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
      1 ?        Ss     0:00 /bin/bash /cygnus-entrypoint.sh
      6 ?        Sl     0:22 /usr/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:6006 -Xmx256m -Xms64m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/log/cygnus/heapDump -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:/var/log/cygnus/gclog -Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,LOGFILE -Duser.timezone=UTC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp /opt/apache-flume/conf:/opt/apache-flume/lib/*:/opt/apache-flume/plugins.d/cygnus/lib/*:/opt/apache-flume/plugins.d/cygnus/libext/* -Djava.library.path= com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication -f /opt/apache-flume/conf/agent.conf -n cygnus-ngsi -p 5080

Depending on which sinks are enabled to be configured admin port could be fixed from 5080 to 5089.
Since some versions ago we recommend use  CYGNUS_SKIP_CONF_GENERATION=true and provide a custom agent.conf by a volume file to cygnus.
